# Null Pointer exception in Processing in Array. Tried everything

Tags: processing

I am  making a 2d side scrolling game and I'm stuck. Im writing the class for the objects which will spawn increasingly and which the Player has to avoid. But sadly I am getting a Nullpointerexception and I cannot figure out why.Before I cleaned up the code in the main and transformed it to a class, the whole thing was working. I think I'm initializing the Array correctly and no variables are left undefined. I've only been using processing for the past months so I might have overseen something.

Thanks a lot for your help

```
 public class Blockfield {
    private int Blockcount;
    private PImage Blockpic;
    private Block block[];

  //Constructor
  public Blockfield (int Blockcount) {
    this.Blockcount = Blockcount; 
    //new array
    block = new Block [Blockcount];
    for ( int i=0; i < Blockcount; i++) {
      block[i] = new Block( width+Blockpic.width, random (height));
    }
  }


  //Draw method for this class
  public void draw () {
    for (int i =frameCount/100; i >0; i--) {
      image ( Blockpic, block[i].x, block[i].y);
      //moves blocks right to left
      block[i].x -=7 ;
      //spawns block when they leave the screen
      if (block[i].x < 0) {
        block[i] = new Block( width+Blockpic.width, random (height));
      }
    }
  }
}

class Block {
float x, y;

Block ( float x, float y) {
this.x= x;
this.y= y;
}
}
```

Main:

```
Blockfield blockfield;
PImage Blockpic;



void setup () { 
  size (1291, 900);
  blockfield = new Blockfield(100);

  Blockpic = loadImage("block2.png");
}


void draw () {
  background ( 10);

}
```

Comment: Do you have a name for that programming language you are using?

Comment: Where is your NullPointer happening?

Comment: You are accessing `Blockpic.width` in your `Blockfield` constructor before `Blockpic` has been assigned.

Comment: Hi. Im using Processing 2.2.1. The Null Pointer is happening at       block[i] = new Block( width+Blockpic.width, random (height));

Comment: Does that mean I have to load the Image in the Class? I have written similiar code where it was sufficient to load the image in the main loop. I tried making     Blockpic a public int but I still get the error.

Comment: Hi, I loaded the image in the class and now the code is compiling. Thanks a lot Phil!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the Processing language, but I'll bet it produces an exception stack trace just like Java does.

Comment: Hi Marius. Thanks for wanting to mark the question as resolved, though we don't do that in the title here. Add a self answer with your solution, and then click the 'tick' mark to indicate it is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying access `Blockpic.width` in your `Blockfield` constructor before `Blockpic` had been assigned. The solution was to load the Image within the constructor of the class.

Working code:

```
public class Blockfield {
    private int Blockcount;
    private PImage Blockpic;
    private Block block[];

  //Constructor
  public Blockfield (int Blockcount) {
    this.Blockcount = Blockcount; 
    Blockpic = loadImage("block2.png");
    //new array
    block = new Block [Blockcount];
    for ( int i=0; i < Blockcount; i++) {
      block[i] = new Block( width+Blockpic.width, random (height));
    }
  }


  //Draw method for this class
  public void draw () {
    for (int i =frameCount/100; i >0; i--) {
      image ( Blockpic, block[i].x, block[i].y);
      //moves blocks right to left
      block[i].x -=7 ;
      //spawns block when they leave the screen
      if (block[i].x < 0) {
        block[i] = new Block( width+Blockpic.width, random (height));
      }
    }
  }
}

class Block {
float x, y;

Block ( float x, float y) {
this.x= x;
this.y= y;
}
}
```

Thanks to everyone for the help!!!